# VBA to Vlookup inside a Loop that compares data between 2 sheets and pastes de repeated values in a 3rd sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My objective is to compare data in a range in Ws1 with data in a range in ws2, and copy those values that repeat in ws3.

Ideally I would like to copy the value found and the rest of the information to the right of that cell (from ws2), but for now I am happy just copying the value found.

I decided to use a loop for this but I was getting an infinite looping, and now that I re-summarize; I am getting:

> range of object _ global failed" error and it points to: "With
>   Range(ws3.cells(i, 1))

```
 Sub quicktests()

Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ColNum, ColNum2 As Long
Dim rng, Range2 As Range
Dim lRow1, lRow2, lCol2 As Integer

ColNum = 9
ColNum2 = 14
lRow1 = 347

Set ws2 = Sheets("Filled today")
With ws2
    lCol2 = .cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'MsgBox lCol2
    lRow2 = .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lRow2
    Set Range2 = .Range(.cells(1, ColNum2), .cells(lRow2, lCol2))
End With

Set ws3 = Sheets("Duplicates filled and hiring")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Reconciliated Recruiment Plan")

For i = 1 To lRow1
    With ws1
        Set rng = .cells(i, ColNum)
    End With

    With Range(ws3.cells(i, 1))
        .Formula = "=VLookup(rng, Range2, ColNum, False)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to be a bit more specific about your an issue to get an answer on stackoverflow.  If you haven't already please read [ask]

Comment: Thanks Mick - I just read it - surely will improve with more use of the site - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just the part with the VLOOKUP:

You can't used range with one cells() it needs a begining and an end, remove the Range wrapper.

The Vlookup; You need to remove the vba part from the string and concatenate it.

```
With ws3.cells(i, 1)
    .Formula = "=VLookup(" & rng.Address(0,0) & "," &  Range2.Address(0,0) & "," &  ColNum & ", False)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Many thanks again Scott - I will retake the work now and will let you know if I manage to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Scott, help!  I have checked and re-checked the ranges and the logic. The formula runs, but it gives me #N/A for all values. I run a regular excel formula next to it and I get multiple repeated values. Any suggestions on how to check for errors. I found a way to lock cells so have also tried it using for the fixed range (1,1), but no results. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi - ok so I have tried many other things, unsuccessfully so far.  My last try was using an answer by MikeD to a similar issue in 2015.  So I created a function and then tried to call that function but I just get an error 'object required'.  This is the code I am using trying to just test the vlookup function.  I am sure the function must be correct as I got it from a solution - but it might be the way I am applying it:   Sheets("Duplicates filled and hiring").Range("a1").Formula = GenLookupFormula(Sheets("Reconciliated Recruitment Plan").["k1"], Sheets("Filled Today").[i2:i347], 1, False)